# How can there be difference in output path?

Tags: c#, exe, file-handling

I've made an application that uses another company's exe to generate some output files based upon calculations done on some input files that are passed into the company's exe... For the exe to work it will look for these input files in the same directory as the location of the exe file.

For the output files, I've found out that the folder that these are output to when the exe is run from my program is different to when the exe is ran in a Windows Explorer..

- When the exe is run in windows explorer these are output to the same directory that the exe is located in
- When my program is ran (in debug from visual studio) these are output to the debug folder

Does anyone know how to make my program output these files to the same directory or why this could be happening?

I don't know anything else about the code within this exe other than its been written in Fortran.

I am running the exe using `Process.Start(exeName).WaitForExit()`

Comment: When you run it in debug mode isnt it essentially running inside the debug folder?  So it is doing the same as running from explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probabbly searching for [Directory.SetCurrentDirectoty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx) function.

Call it *before* actually executing external exe program. Pass into it a folder complete path where you would like to see the output files, this *may* resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you run an application, each time it should got a current folder as context, I think it's that exe actually using current folder for output, and run your program and debug causing current folder difference. You can try use Directory.SetCurrentDirectory to set current folder and see if that help

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the [working directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx) to the directory where both the apps are.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set your working directory for your C# application, but only for the ran program, use the `Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` property.

Example:

```
var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("myProgram.exe");
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "myDirectory";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```